# Limit the size of a long?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, .net-4.8

I have a table in the (oracle) database that has a column of `NUMBER(12)`. I can't use `int` in C# because that is small, so I used `long`. But `long` is too big for this table column. Is there any way to limit the size of a `long` before I send the data to the database? Otherwise I will get an error ORA-21525, since I exceed the size of the table column. The data send to the database is actually a `List<long>`.

Comment: Show us how you declared your parameter in your well parameterized sql query, show us the table def, the code that invokes the query and an example of the data that causes the problem. If your example data is a long of `1234567890123` then it's really going to be c#'s job to not send numbers greater than 999,999,999,999..

Comment: Where do you get your values from?

Comment: What will you do with longs that exceed, by the way?

Comment: Wrap the long in a struct and use Value Conversion if you are using EF. Other wise in your constructor add a check.

Comment: whatever type you are using in C#, why are you trying to insert numbers bigger than the precision allowed in the column ? where those numbers are coming from ? Either you have data which does not fit your column size, thus change the precision in the column, or you are inserting numbers that should not be inserted, thus discard them

Comment: `Long` is a 8-byte integer, it cannot be restricted as it is built-in datatype. Do check before you store some value in that `Long` at the app side or use `Decimal`. Nevertheless, why you try to store the values that cannot fit into storage?

Comment: the values of long come from the table. So the user selects via a multiselect dropdown the elements he needs and then becomes a result. So the c# part is like a filter. Normally the long should not be bigger than the table can swallow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious solution would be to use a custom number type that restricts the range of values for the number. Something like

```
public readonly struct Number12{
    public long Value {get;}
    public Number12(long num){
        if(num > 999999999999 || num < -999999999999 ){
           throw new ArgumentException("number out of rage " +num);
        }
        Value = num;
    }
   // Add operators, conversions etc
}
```

An advantage of this would be that it is obvious that this number has some special rules. But it will be more cumbersome to use, and may cause issues if the database is changed in the future.